# How to change marker point size in charts_flutter?

Tags: flutter, graph, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to find a way to change the marker point data in the time series graph from `charts_flutter` dependency.

[image]

As you can see the picture above, I am trying to change the marker point size. I am trying to make it small.

Here is my graph code:

```
return Container(
            height: 250,
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: charts.TimeSeriesChart(
                      series,
                      animate: true,
                      defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(
                        includeArea: true,
                        includeLine: true,
                        includePoints: true,
                        strokeWidthPx: 1
                      ),
                      dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
                      behaviors: [
                        charts.SlidingViewport(),
                        charts.PanAndZoomBehavior(),
                        charts.SeriesLegend(
                          position: charts.BehaviorPosition.top,
                          horizontalFirst: false,
                          cellPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 80, 
                            top: 10, 
                            bottom: 4
                          ),
                        ),
                        charts.SelectNearest(
                          eventTrigger: charts.SelectionTrigger.hover
                        ),
                        charts.LinePointHighlighter(
                          symbolRenderer: CustomCircleSymbolRenderer(size: size),
                        ),
                      ],
                      selectionModels: [
                        charts.SelectionModelConfig(
                        type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
                        changedListener: (charts.SelectionModel model) {
                          if(model.hasDatumSelection) {
                            final tankVolumeValue = model.selectedSeries[0].measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index).round();
                            final dateValue = model.selectedSeries[0].domainFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index);
                            CustomCircleSymbolRenderer.value = '$dateValue \n $tankVolumeValue L';
                        }
                      })
                    ]),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Please provide some code that you already tried.

Comment: I have edit the question

Comment: try add `radiusPx` like `defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(radiusPx:1)`

Answer (score -1):

I use the includePoints in **true** and radiusPx parameters of the defaultRender option in LineChart.

```
charts.LineChart(
.
.
.
defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(
        includeArea: false,
        areaOpacity: 0,
        strokeWidthPx: 1,
        roundEndCaps: true,
        includePoints: true,
        radiusPx: 0.1,
      ),
.
.
.
)
```

Comment: radiusPx already mentioned in comment of @Sam Chan

Comment: yes, but not the part of includePoints in true...

Comment: `includePoints: true` is part of the poster's code.